# React with Typescript - is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working with ReacJs and Typescript.

When I'm authenticating a user, using the methods below, I get the following error message:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): auth.authenticate is not a function
onSubmit
src/components/Login/index.tsx:33
  30 |
  31 | const onSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  32 | event.preventDefault();
> 33 | await auth.authenticate(
     | ^34 | values.username,
  35 | values.password
  36 | );
```

My inexperience must be leading me to this mistake. I'm still very confused by Typescript declarations.

I present below the codes of the methods I'm using:

Login.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../../context/AuthProvider/useAuth"
import { useHistory } from "react-router"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Label,
  Input,
  wrapper,
  FormWrapper,
  Date,
  Submit,
  Button,
  LoginQuestion
} from "./styles";

const Login = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const history = useHistory();

  const initialState = {
    username: "",
    password: "",
  };

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await auth.authenticate(      **<--------- Error on this line.**
      values.username,
      values.password
    );
    history.push('/');
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <FormWrapper>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} noValidate >
          <Date>
            <Label htmlFor="username">User</Label>
            <Input type='text' name='username' onChange={onChange} />
          </Date>
          <Date>
            <Label htmlFor="password">Password</Label>
            <Input type='password' name='password' onChange={onChange} />
          </Date>
          <Submit>
            <Button>Login</Button>
          </Submit>
          <LoginQuestion>
            <Link
              to="/signup">Create an account
            </Link>
          </LoginQuestion>
          <LoginQuestion>
            <Link
              to="/signup">Recover password
            </Link>
          </LoginQuestion>
        </form>
      </FormWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default Login
```

useAuth.tsx

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { AuthContext } from "."

export const useAuth = () => {
  
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  
  return context;
}
```

AuthProvider.tsx

```
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { IAuthProvider, IContext, IUser } from "./types";
import { getUserLocalStorage, LoginRequest, setUserLocalStorage } from "./util";

export const AuthContext = createContext<IContext>({} as IContext)

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: IAuthProvider) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>()
  useEffect(() => {
    const user = getUserLocalStorage();

    if (user) {
      setUser(user);
    }
  }, [])

  async function authenticate(
    username:string,
    password: string
  ) {
    const response = await LoginRequest(username, password);
    const payload = {token: response?.token};

    setUser(payload);
    setUserLocalStorage(payload);
  }

  function logout () {
    setUser(null);
    setUserLocalStorage(null);
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{...user, authenticate, logout}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

In this file I declare the interfaces.

types.ts

```
export interface IUser {
  username?: string;
  token?: string;
}

export interface IContext extends IUser {
  authenticate: (username: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
  logout: () => void;
}

export interface IAuthProvider {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

export interface ILoginRequest {
  token: string;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly you have defined an authentication context provider component; but I can't see where you are actually using `AuthProvider` to wrap your component. There's a lot of code here so I may be missing something, but any hints appreciated.

Comment: Exactly!!!! I forgot to involve your call before router.
Thanks for the observation, which led me to the solution.

Comment: Just for completeness, this is not a Typescript issue, this is a JavaScript runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6801926/marcus), in the comment above, I was not calling the AuthProvider function, and this caused the error in question. Thanks to [Marcus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6801926/marcus).

AuthProvider must be called before routes, according to the code below:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { AuthProvider } from './context/AuthProvider'
import ProtectedLayout from './components/ProtectedLayout';
import Routers from './routers';
import Sidebar from './components/sidebar/Sidebar';

const App: FC = () => {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <ProtectedLayout>
                    <Sidebar />
                </ProtectedLayout>
                <Routers />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```